# Can "tit" be used for men's nipples?

Tags: word-usage, slang, offensive-language

I know that "tit" means nipple, and can be used to refer the to the breast as a whole, and has a few unrelated meanings.

But can it be used in a normal context to mean a man's nipples, or only a woman's nipples?

I've heard of the expression "As useless as tits on a bull", but it's a derogatory expression, so I don't know if it's a good example.

Comment: *[Man tit](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/man_tit)* or *man boob*, though being slang and can be considered rude and offensive, is used. (I can remember hearing it on a medical reality show.)

Comment: Yes and no. _Can_ it be used? Sure, it could. Is it used in a _normal_ context? Not usually. You can Google for expressions like _on his tit_ or _under his tit_ and find a smattering of examples, like [this one](http://s214.photobucket.com/user/jenn6376/media/Summer%20Camp/2276.jpg.html). (If you want to conduct your own search, I'll just caution: since the term is generally considered vulgar, many of the results you find will be from vulgar contexts. It's not a gentleman's term.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. *tit* typically means a woman's breast.

> [tit](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/thesaurus/american/tit#tit_4) - a woman's breast. Also [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Tits) and [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tit).

If you want to refer to a man's breast, it'd be '[man's boob](http://www.nhs.uk/chq/Pages/885.aspx?CategoryID=61)' or [gynecomastia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gynecomastia). But then if you quote this term, you are **no longer** referring to a flat chest or nipples on a flat chest that I think you are concerned about. That's because when we refer a body part as a boob, it is never flat. That's why, men don't have boobs but a flat chest. When they are enlarged, the condition is referred to as gynecomastia.

Comment: That's strange - I thought it had a primary meaning of "nipple", and "breast" was a secondary meaning, and that the secondary meaning was a synecdoche.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm no, tit generally refers to the whole breast; **teat** which is by some pronounced identically to **tit** refers to the nipple, which may be a source of some confusion.  I've always assumed **teat** is the etymological ancestor of **tit** but I don't actually know that.

Comment: That's the right word, but on a learner's forum, it might be worth noting that _gynecomastia_ is reserved almost exclusively for a medical context. Also, the question is asking about a man's nipple, not a man's breast.

Comment: @J.R. Agreed. I introduced that term purely to specify man boob. Also, I clarified that what he meant by tit is different than what's it specified in the dictionaries. I tried answering with multiple approaches since to OP, *tit* exclusively meant a 'nipple' (from his comment and I had guessed it!).

Answer (score 1):

I'd not use tit to refer to a man, if not for joking.

Noun. 
1. (Anatomy) a female breast
2. (Anatomy) a teat or nipple
3. a girl or young woman

Source: [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tit?showCookiePolicy=true).